# keytool - data isn't an object ID (tag = 49)

Tags: java, x509certificate, keytool, client-certificates

I'm trying to create some Certificates in Keytool within Java / Bin folder.

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias CertfileProg -file "C:\Danv\Techno.cer" 
-keystore "C:\Danv\Techno.jks"
```

I get the error:

```
keytool error: java.security.cert.certificateParsingException: java.io.IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = 49)
```

Request any support with this.

Comment: `-keystroke` is not an option for `keytool`; I assume you actually used `-keystore` but posted the wrong thing to make it more difficult to help you. Although file extensions do not actually control contents, people _usually_ use the extension `.csr` for a CSR (Certificate Signing Request), which is not a certificate. `keytool -import[cert]` can only import a single certificate (to a trustedCert or privatekey) or a certificate chain (to a privatekey); it cannot import a CSR, so if that file _does_ in fact contain a CSR, what you are doing makes no sense and is impossible.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for answering. I've made the edits. I've got a certificate file too .cer . Please see if the updated one makes sense? - Thanks

Comment: Renaming the file doesn't do anything, as @dave_thompson_085 has already stated. *Is* it a certificate file, or is it still a CSR?

Comment: @user207421 .. Thanks.. Sure, it's a Certificate this time with .cer extension. Not renamed file.

When I run that I get a different error.

keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Public keys  in reply and keystore don't match